# Using last Snapshot version of Mapbox Navigation SDK v2.0.0

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm trying to use the latest Snapshot for new navigation sdk 2.0.0 which is supposed to be used with Mapbox Maps SDK v10.0.0-beta.13. However, the latest version I'm able to grab from maven is 9.6.1

```
maven {
    url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/snapshots/maven'
    authentication {
        basic(BasicAuthentication)
    }
    credentials {
        username = 'mapbox'
        password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
    }
}

maven {
    url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
    authentication {
        basic(BasicAuthentication)
    }
    credentials {
        username = 'mapbox'
        password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
    }
}


implementation 'com.mapbox.navigation:core:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:X.X.X'
```

How can I get such version? I tried all these without success

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:10.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:10.0.0-beta.13'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:10.0.0-beta'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:10.0.0'
```

I can not use 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT for the ui-sdk either.

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.navigation:ui:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

I can add a regular release version for the navigation ui but I'm getting several internal issues which I think might be due to the version incompatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow the steps outlined in [Mapbox documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/beta/maps/guides/install/) for the Maps SDK 10.0?

Telling from your code it is hard to tell if you were. Can you ensure that you only add the releases branch of maven to check for the SDK? Also, can you make sure to specify the libraries to implement in your application level `build.gradle`, and not in the module level `build.gradle`?

Comment: Thank you!
I was indeed not aware of that documentation. I can use now the Maps SDK 10.0. Basically I needed to add  

 `implementation 'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.0.0-beta.12'`  

What I was not able to download was the Navigation UI SDK v2.0.0, I thought it would be accessible in a similar way than the navigation core SDK v2.0.0 but is not.  

This is what I'm trying:  

 `implementation 'com.mapbox.navigation:ui:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT' `  


 Did I misunderstand it and there is not such available navigation ui snapshot?

Comment: Answering to myself, the artifacts for the navigation ui were split in navigation SDK 2.0

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/wiki/2.0-Navigation-SDK-Migration-Guide#artifact-name-changes